# Blocking Openam externalization

Tags: openam

We are blocked by our security team to go live with openam because of below issue. We have openam deployed in tomcat in server1 (Tomcat). We have agent and HTMLs in Server2. Agent redirects all the unauthenticated requests from server2 (Apache/httpd) where html is deployed to server1 where openam is deployed.

The problem is we don’t want to open server2 for public considering security risk. Is it possible for an web agent deployed on server1 to connect to openam deployed on server2 which is not a opened/externalized server? How we have to externalize the openam server, how to hide all console stuff and block all API calls?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to externalize the login interface of OpenAM, but you would need to write a custom login application for that. This custom app then could have direct access to the OpenAM server to perform the REST calls necessary to authenticate end-users.

Once you have the login UI in place on a public server, you can change the agent configuration to use that login UI for the Login and Logout URLs.